webpack ignores mini-css-extract-plugin plugins options
I've been trying to setup webpack for a personal project and everything has worked out well except that for some reason webpack is ignoring the options I'm giving it for production for mini-css-extract-plugin and is instead using the default filename of [hash][ext] when it should be using [name]-[hash].css . This is what I have in my webpack files.
webpack.common.js:
const path = require("path");
const HtmlWebpackPlugin = require("html-webpack-plugin");

module.exports = {
    devtool: false,
    entry: './src/index.js',
    output: {
        path: path.resolve(__dirname, "dist"),
        clean: true,
    },
    module: {
        rules: [
            {
                test: /\.html$/,
                use: ["html-loader"]
            },
            {
                test: /\.jpe?g$|\.gif$|\.png$|\.PNG$|\.svg$/,
                type: 'asset/resource',
                generator: {
                    filename: 'images/[name][ext]'
                }
            }
        ]
    },
    plugins: [
        new HtmlWebpackPlugin({
            template: "./src/template.html",
            templateParameters: {
                title: 'Lister',
            },
            inject: 'head',
            scriptLoading: 'defer'
        }),
    ]
}


webpack.dev.js
const path = require("path");
const common = require("./webpack.common");
const { merge } = require("webpack-merge");

module.exports = merge(common, {
    mode: 'development',
    devtool: false,
    output: {
        filename: 'main.js',
    },
    module: {
        rules: [
            {
                test: /\.css$/,
                use: [
                    "style-loader",
                    "css-loader"
                ]
            },
            {
                test: /\.jpe?g$|\.gif$|\.png$|\.PNG$|\.svg$/,
                type: 'asset/resource',
                generator: {
                    filename: 'images/[name][ext]'
                }
            }
        ]
    },
});


webpack.prod.js where I specified the filename options:
const path = require("path");
const common = require("./webpack.common");
const { merge } = require("webpack-merge");
const MiniCssExtractPlugin = require("mini-css-extract-plugin");

module.exports = merge(common, {
    mode: 'production',
    devtool: false,
    output: {
        filename: 'main-[contenthash].js',
    },
    plugins: [
        new MiniCssExtractPlugin({
            filename: 'css/[name]-[hash].css',
        }),
    ],
    module: {
        rules: [
            {
                test: /\.css$/i,
                use: [
                    MiniCssExtractPlugin.loader,
                    "css-loader"
                ],
            },
            {
                test: /\.jpe?g$|\.gif$|\.png$|\.PNG$|\.svg$/,
                type: 'asset/resource',
                generator: {
                    filename: 'images/[name]-[hash][ext]'
                }
            }
        ]
    }
});


after building using the webpack.prod.js file I got these files in my dist file:
b88d04fba731603756b1.css  images  index.html  main-31d6cfe0d16ae931b73c.js
when I was hoping to get something like this:
css  images  index.html  main-31d6cfe0d16ae931b73c.js
and in the css directory I was hoping to have something such as:
style-b88d04fba731603756b1.css

I managed to solve it by overriding the default with assetModuleFilename so now it defaults to making files in the css directory with the filename of [name]-[hash][ext] and making an exception for files with the extension of .png, .svg, .gif etc. so that they're put in a images/ folder with the same filename convention. Below is the code working
const path = require("path");
const common = require("./webpack.common");
const { merge } = require("webpack-merge");
const MiniCssExtractPlugin = require("mini-css-extract-plugin");

module.exports = merge(common, {
    mode: 'production',
    devtool: false,
    output: {
        filename: 'main-[contenthash].js',
        assetModuleFilename: 'css/[name]-[hash][ext]',
    },
    plugins: [
        new MiniCssExtractPlugin(),
    ],
    module: {
        rules: [
            {
                test:/\.css$/,
                use: [MiniCssExtractPlugin.loader, "css-loader"]
            },
            {
                test: /\.jpe?g$|\.gif$|\.png$|\.PNG$|\.svg$/,
                type: 'asset/resource',
                generator: {
                    filename: 'images/[name]-[hash][ext]'
                }
            }
        ]
    }
});

This is only what has been changed
        assetModuleFilename: 'css/[name]-[hash][ext]',
    },
    plugins: [
        new MiniCssExtractPlugin(),
    ],

